# Temperature and airflow in a large empty case

Tags: cooling, computer-building, temperature, case

My brother is looking into building a home computer and has asked my opinion on the components he's picked out.  One concern that I've had is that he has chosen a Full ATX Tower, but the rest of the system is rather bare-bones (micro-ATX mobo, 8GB ram, NVidia GTX 750TI, Intel i5-4440).  Now, I know that there's some questions regarding running an open case and temperature variations due to lack of airflow, but what about a fairly large case which will probably be almost completely empty based on this build?  Will this cause issues with temperatures?

I've heard in the past that large empty cases can have temperature issues (especially for passively cooled components) due to turbulence factors.  A couple acquaintances of mine have heard similar, but I'm unable to find any source of evidence for this.  Can anyone say for sure if there could be an issue here, and provide some source of proof for it?  If it's a "it depends" scenario, what variables are important?

Comment: Do you have the make and model of this Full ATX case handy? There are all sorts of different cases. The nicer ones have more fans and more air ports and generally the airflow is from the bottom front to the top back, with optional ports in the side and top. Also, in general, the less clutter there is inside a case to disrupt the airflow, the better. This is why it is good to run your cables behind your motherboard and to zip tie them.

Comment: I can do one better, and provide the [whole parts list](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/3BqkE) he gave me (though he's since changed the RAM choice).  It's an NZXT Phantom.  I know that typically the less clutter the better, I'm just concerned that there may be either diminishing, or worse, negative returns after a certain point.

Comment: I generally buy large cases, and have never had any problem engineering an air-flow pattern that keeps my parts cool (and NZXT provides guidance for that in their manuals, in my experience). Look at it this way; if you have a large case, you can adjust your cooling as needed, but in a small case, it can be very hard, if not impossible, to get a clear flow with all the parts jumbled together and cables all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Phantom NZXT White
- Full Tower, 5 Peripheral Bays, 7 Hard Drive Bays, 7 Expansion Slots, Front Audio/USB 2.0x2/eSATA
- http://www.nzxt.com/product/detail/34-phantom

Wow. That's an awesome case. I see why you guys are ignoring the size in favor of the aesthetic. That case has 4 fans including a fan to cool the hard drive bay. Everything will be nice and cool. You're also using an aftermarket heatsink for your CPU which is another good choice. I don't anticipate you having any problems with the cooling of this system.

I agree that this case is bigger than needed, since your motherboard is Micro ATX and the case fits an Extended ATX. You could definitely go a size lower and just do a Mid Tower if you wanted.